# Are there meaningful names for linear dependence theorems taught in college?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

[image]

[image]

It seems like everywhere I look, even outside of my own university, these theorems are referred to as 8 and 9, but very possibly because they use the same textbook I do.

I would really like to know if these theorems have names or if I reference "Theorem 8" to a mathematician they'll instantly know what I'm talking about.

Comment: These are just basic facts about linear independence. And no, nobody outside of your class will know what "theorem X" means without any context.

Comment: shouldnt all theorems have names though?

Comment: @notacorn only big ones :) the rest can be numbers in some paper

Comment: If all theorems had names, we would run out of names for theorems really fast, and we would eventually have to call them things like "The X218bfd8 Theorem". This is not useful, so we do not give a name to every theorem (there are infinitely many theorems)

Comment: Theorem 8 could perhaps be referenced as "a consequence of [the dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)". Theorem 9 seems obvious enough that it wouldn't require any justification

Comment: There is the [Rand-Nulity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), which implies your  8 and 9, and is sometimes remembered by name.

Comment: Theorem 8 could be seen as a consequence of [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).